# Mongoose, filter results of a fulltext search

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, full-text-search

I used to have a `Comment` schema, where I held `author`, `comment` and `commentID` fields, essentially duplicating author's name for every comment that belonged to him. So I refactored it as following. Now I have an `Author` model with an array of his comments, it does feel better but I've lost the ability to query `commentBody` via fulltext search. Before I would just query `Comment` model with the term and it returned me every comment that met the criteria.

```
const authorSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: { type: String, unique: true, index: true },
  comments: [{
    commentID: { type: String, unique: true },
    commentBody: { type: String, index: 'text' },
    created_at: { type: Date, default: Date.now }
  }],
  ...
  // other unrelated fields
});
```

But now when I'm trying to query `Author` model directly like this:

```
Author.find({ $text: { $search: `${req.params.term}` } })
  .select('name comments')
  .exec((error, result) => {
    res.json(result);
  });
```

it righteously so returns me every match of `Author` if at least one of his comments meets searching criteria. I've spent couple of hours reading Mongoose and MongoDB's docs, but I still  can't write a proper query that will return *only* matched comments within the comments array, i.e. for term `lorem` I want the follow response:

```
{
  name: "Jane",
  comments: [
    {
      commentBody: "Lorem dolor",
      commentID: "42",
    },
    {
      commentBody: "Lorem lipsum.",
      commentID: "43",
    },
  ]
},
{
  name: "Doe",
  comments: [
    {
      commentBody: "Dolor lorem",
      commentID: "44",
    },
    {
      commentBody: "Lipsum lorem.",
      commentID: "45",
    },
  ]
}
```

Comment: MongoDB does not "filter" arrays within documents in search results, other than for a basic case to return the "first matched" element, but with normal queries and not "text" ones. Chances are you really want a [`$regex`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/regex/) query along with the general process in [Retrieve only the queried element in an object array in MongoDB collection](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3985214/retrieve-only-the-queried-element-in-an-object-array-in-mongodb-collection).

Comment: But really, unless this is discarding 100's of array elements per document that do not match the conditions then just "filter the arrays" returned in the documents in your client code. The database is doing it's job by returning the "documents" that match conditions, and even in the "order of relevance" which is what a "text" search is actually for. As said, if you expect something else then you actually meant to use `$regex` instead.

Comment: @NeilLunn thank you for the response. I think regex would be quite slow, as the database is pretty large and search requests initiated from client are frequent. Filtering on the client is not an option either, since there are like a hundred of authors with dozens of thousands comments. Although it was pretty fast when I stored every comment separately and could utilize text index, now it seems that I should try to setup sphinx or elastic for the designated search purpose.